# create simple HTTP server and stop when user visits specific URL

Tags: python, pyqt5, webserver, pyside6, pyqt6

I want to create and run an HTTP server in the background and listen to the last visited URL. If the user visits a specific URL (e.g. /stop-server), I want to stop the server.

Since there are so many options, I am confused what I should use and I don't want to use complicated libraries for something so simple.

※ I am using (and I want to use) PySide6 v6.3 for this project by the way.

I made a working example using "http.server", but I am not happy with it because it looks a little tricky to me, so I am worried about "unexpected" bugs.

What library should I use?

**update:**

*The tricky parts I am considering are:*
1- wrapping the HttpServer class in a function for using callbacks, I am not sure if it is good thing to do

2- using QThreads (instead of QRunnable) and forcing it to terminate because I can not shutdown the web_server properly.
(the `shutdown()` method (of web_server) doesn't terminate the QThread, so I have to do it manually.)

3- I am not using the built-in Qt method. There is QHttpServer but it's only available from version 6.4.

```py
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer

from PySide6.QtCore import QThread, QRunnable, Slot, QThreadPool, Signal, QObject
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QVBoxLayout

_HOST = "localhost"
_PORT = 9999


def server_handler(callback):
    class HttpServer(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
        def do_GET(self):
            self.send_response(200)
            self.send_header("Content-type", "text/html")
            self.end_headers()

            self.wfile.write(bytes(f"<p>{self.path}</p>", "utf-8"))

            if self.path == "/stop-server":
                callback()

    return HttpServer


class Worker(QThread):
    finished = Signal(bool)

    def __init__(self):
        super(Worker, self).__init__()
        self.web_server = None
        self.setTerminationEnabled(True)

    @Slot()
    def run(self) -> None:
        http_server = server_handler(self.close_server)
        self.web_server = HTTPServer((_HOST, _PORT), http_server)
        print("Server started ", f"http://{_HOST}:{_PORT}")
        self.web_server.serve_forever()

    def close_server(self):
        print("Server stopped")
        self.finished.emit(True)
        self.web_server.server_close()


class Application(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Application, self).__init__()

        self.threadpool = QThreadPool()
        self.server = Worker()
        self.server.finished.connect(self.finished)
        self.server.start()

        self.show()

    def finished(self):
        print("terminate")
        self.server.terminate()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication()
    _ = Application()
    app.exec()
```

Comment: What is it that looks "tricky" to you?

Comment: Maybe it's tricky because you made it so. Why are you creating a new server class in a function, instead of creating an *actual* class that behaves according to your needs? QRunnable is just a basic threading interface, QThread is actually a *common* interface (in fact, there always exist at least one QThread interface, and all QObjects can recall it), so, using it is not "tricky", is quite common instead. Unless you need *multiple* http servers, just subclass QThread and do everything from there.

Comment: I tried to use HttpServer class without wrapping in a function but I couldn't able to run `callback` function. as long as it is not my own class, I can't edit so much and if you are talking about creating a new class, I just thought it is unnecessary but if there is better way or a way I don't know about, I'd like to hear. And good to hear that using Qthread is not tricky.

Answer (score 0):

Flask could be a very simple solution for you to quickly and easily spin up a server to test this out on your machine.

From Flask's [quickstart guide](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/) (plus a route added for your use case):

hello.py:

```
from flask import Flask, request
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello, World!'


@app.route('/server-shutdown')
def shutdown():
    func = request.environ.get('werkzeug.server.shutdown')
    if func is None:
        raise RuntimeError('Not running with the Werkzeug Server')
    func()
    return "Shutting down..."
```

and then on the command line in the same directory:

```
$ export FLASK_APP=hello.py
$ flask run
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/
```

then try `curl http://127.0.0.1:5000/` and `curl  http://127.0.0.1:5000/server-shutdown` -- you'll see that the latter shuts down the app.

There are many great guides to doing more with flask and great support for it out there. IMO the best is [hackers and slackers](https://hackersandslackers.com/series/build-flask-apps/) for a quick intro and Miguel Grinberg's series are incredible.

Comment: Is "Flask" a library I can use with PySide6?

Comment: You should be able to run them separately, or make a Flask server that calls functionality from your other program, but it depends on what you're trying to do. If you could give a little more info about how exactly you want your GUI to interact with this server behavior I might be able to help a little more.

Comment: @leonious please don't use line numbers in code snippets; they are not as useful as one might think, and also make copy/paste very annoying.

Comment: Sorry, just copied from vim. Edited